# Band structure calculation algorithm

Tags: open-source, scientific-computing

I am searching for an Open Source program that calculates the band structure of semiconductors for several input like effective masses etc.

Is there anything like that out there?

Comment: Do you search for an algorithm or a program that implements a specific algorithm?

Comment: No. The method or algorithm doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

I searched GIT hub for you, because that is a common ground for very specific open source development.

It results in 6 matches:
 1. Search 'semiconductors band' [3 hits](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=semiconductors%20band&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults)
 2. Search 'semiconductors effective mass' [3 hits](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=semiconductors%20effective%20mass&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults)

Of these 6 matches [Effective Mass Calculator](http://afonari.com/emc/) has the best odds:

> Helper script for CRYSTAL: cry-getE.pl In case of CRYSTAL, cry-getE.pl:
>   script should be used in order to obtain file with the energies on the
>   grid. The script takes two k-points at a time and **runs band structure
>   calculations** (using runprop script from the CRYSTAL package).

License: MIT open source